# Write NULL in database, If variable have None

Tags: mysql, python-3.x

```
var = None
id = 123
name = 'dev'

query = "INSERT INTO Table('id', 'name', 'val') VALUES ('"+str(id)+"','"+str(name)+"','"+str(var)+"' );"
```

I want to store "**var**" value as "**NULL**" into mySQL database database.
If I put any other value in place of **None** it stored successfully, but If this value is None I want to store *NULL** into database.
Thanks in advance

Comment: `query = "INSERT INTO Table('id', 'name', 'val') VALUES ('"+str(id)+"','"+str(name)+"',NULLIF('"+str(var)+"', 'None)' );"`?

Comment: Don't build SQL strings by yourself but use parameterized queries.

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this:

```
c.execute('INSERT INTO expenses VALUES (:amount , :category , :message , :date)' , {'amount' : amount , 'category' : category , 'message' : message , 'date' : date}) 

    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
```

Comment: This could use an explanation along with the answer. It would also be helpful if your code snippet followed what the author used.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).